# When does data in Oracle materialized view actually change?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have an Oracle materialized view refreshed on demand. Since the view is pretty large, it takes a while to update. I am wondering: when do the updates really become visible to the queries that try read the view? Does RDBMS update the view in a buffer and then makes it visible when update is complete? Or will the changes gradually become visible to the reader? Is this possible to control this?

Comment: The refresh is transactional and the commit is done at the end

Answer (score 0):

Materialized views can be refreshed on commit or on demand.
Oracle's documentation is quite good

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm#i2116410

To have materialized views refresh incrementally you must use the FAST option and you must have materialized view logs to capture changes on the source tables.

If you schedule the demanded refreshes frequently there will be less work to be done for each refresh. If you schedule them less frequently there will be more work to be done. You need to investigate how changes on the source tables are distributed over time to choose well.

Changes will be visible to users when the refresh (whatever size) commits.

Comment: Right, thanks, but you are answering not the question that was asked.

Comment: Sorry about that @IvanGeideko - I'll update my answer